# Salesforce Winter'18 - Health Cloud

Tags: health-cloud

As per videos and documentations, It is mentioned that Health cloud is available in lightning now. However, I can't find any lightning app for Health Cloud after platform upgrade.
Do i need to do something to make that app visible?

Comment: could you link the documentation please?

Answer (score 2):

This is from the documentation -

> Turning on Health Cloud Lightning Experience Console is a very simple
>   task—just add the app to your org and assign users.
>
> Use the Lightning Experience Migration Assistant as your control
>   center for tackling these steps. From Setup in Salesforce Classic,
>   click Get Started in the Migration Assistant tile at the top of the
>   menu.
>
> Once you enable the Health Cloud Lightning Experience Console, your
>   users can access the console using the App switcher. Users with Health
>   Cloud Standard or Health Cloud Admin permission sets can access Health
>   Cloud - Lightning Console app. You need the Health Cloud Admin
>   permission set to access the Health Cloud - Lightning Admin app.

Source - [Enable Health Cloud Lightning Experience Console for Your Users](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.health_cloud.meta/health_cloud/admin_enable_lightning_console.htm)

You also might want to go through this checklist - [Health Cloud Lightning Console Setup Checklist](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.health_cloud.meta/health_cloud/admin_LEX_setup_checklist.htm)

Comment: Thnx for the reference.  I will chk it completely and mark it as answer.